# How do I get only the new tweets per request using Twitter API?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, twitter

I'm trying to get new tweets containing some hashtag from Twitter API. The thing I'm interested in is the number of new tweets each time I request the results. So like this:

```
10:20 AM: 100 tweets containing #google 
10:22 AM: 130 tweets containing #google
```

But right now somehow my results stay the same. This is my code:

PHP (tweets.php):

```
<?php 

$json = file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23apple:)&include_entities=true&rpp=100', true);
echo $json;
?>
```

Javascript:

```
function getTweets() {
    var tweets = 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: "tweets.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function(data) {
            $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
                console.log(value.entities);
                tweets++;

            });

    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval("getTweets()", 5000);

});
```

How can I get only the updates?

**EDIT: My code works, but the results are not really updates. They are just the same results over and over again.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function(){ getTweets();}, 5000);

});
```

Comment: You were passing your function as a string in setInterval. It requires an executable code in first argument.

Comment: The result still contains the older tweets each time mixed with new ones. How can I just get the new ones after last time?

Comment: you have to specify this in your server side script that grabs the data. Extract only last one, two or three items from returned json array. because we can't make a guess that which is latest tweet

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents()` returns a **string** data type, not **JSON**. see if this works:

```
$json = json_encode(file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23apple:)&include_entities=true&rpp=100', true));
```

Comment: this might be due to `var tweets = 0;` at the start of your function. this would render `tweets++;` useless. maybe try something like `var tweetCounter += tweets;` ?